# Can't install OSX Snow Leopard via VirtualBox?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, osx-snow-leopard

I am having trouble installing Mac OSX Snow Leopard using VirtualBox. Everything goes fine until I try to install it. When it finishes installing, it boots back up and prompts me to install it again. It keeps on doing this.

I am using the ISO made by Hazard and trying to do this on Sierra.

Comment: Is Virtualization enabled on your computer board?

Comment: Of course. I have a Macbook Pro from mid-2012 so I am pretty sure it's already enabled.